# How I can skip callback in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller looks like

```
class BarsController < ApplicationController
   after_action :some_method, only: [:index]

   def index
      get_cache = $redis.get('some_key')
      if get_cache.present?
          # i want to skip after_action callback in here
      else
          # other stuff
      end
   end
end
```

How can I skip `after_action :some_method` if `get_cache` is present? I know I can do this with conditional like this

```
class BarsController < ApplicationController
   after_action :some_method, only: [:index], unless: :check_redis

   def index
      get_cache = $redis.get('some_key')
      if get_cache.present?
          # i want to skip after_action callback in here
      else
          # other stuff
      end
   end


   private

   def check_redis
     $redis.get('some_key')
   end
end
```

But I think that is redundant, because should multiple get to redis.

Comment: You should be using `after_action` instead of the deprecated `after_filter`

Comment: @TamerShlash I knew that.. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
class BarsController < ApplicationController

   after_action :some_method, only: [:index], unless: :skip_action?

   def index
      get_cache = $redis.get('some_key')
      if get_cache.present?
          @skip_action = true
          # i want to skip after_action callback in here
      else
          # other stuff
      end
   end


   private

   def skip_action?
     @skip_action
   end
end
```

You can also use `attr_accessor :skip_action` instead of private method because controller is just object.

Comment: It's also the case that `some_method` could just bail out: `return if @skip_action` as the first line in that method.

Comment: Already have simillar solution, but I make instance variable from `get_cache` to `@get_cache`, and call on condition